# Spotlight missing on ground

Tags: lighting

The spotlight is not showing up on a plane. This issue has been raised in previous posts, but the individual was using an older version of Blender. I couldn't make sense of the answers to post as I am using a newer version of Blender.

1st image: View from camera mode. Rendered with Cycles
[image]

2nd image: Rendered image view. No spotlight shown.
[image]

3rd image: Plane (ground) selected to show the settings for it.
[image]

Any suggestions what changes I need to make to have the spotlight appear on that plane (ground) ?

Comment: I can see the effect of the spotlight in the second screenshot. If you want a more pronounced spotlight, then you have to increase the intensity and reduce the *Blend* (for a sharper transition).

Comment: I reduced the Blend to zero and concerning the intensity, (assuming you are refering to the Power setting), I increased that but it still did not make a difference.